# JavaScriptのaddEventListenerを使って背景色を一瞬だけ変えるコードを教えてください

Tags: javascript

いつもお世話になっています。下記の質問についてご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたらご教示を願います。

---

### 【質問の主旨】

index.htmlにdivタグがあります。そのdivタグはピンク色の背景をしたボックスになっています。
そのJavaScriptを用いて、ボックスをクリックしたときに一瞬だけオレンジに変更するためにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？

### 【質問の補足】

#### JavaScript (js/main.js)

背景色を切り替えるためのJavaScriptコードについて以下の通り記述しています。

```js
"use strict"; 
{
  const box1 = document.getElementById('box1');
  const box2 = document.getElementById('box2');
  const box3 = document.getElementById('box3');
  let i = 0

  function styleBackground() {
    box1.style.background = 'orange';
    if (ox1.style.background === 'orange') {
      // backgroundが'orange'であれば'pink'に戻す
　　　 box1.style.background = 'pink';
    }
  }

  box1.addEventListener('click', () => {
    styleBackground();
  }); 

  box2.addEventListener('click', () => {
    box2.textContent = i++;
  });

  box3.addEventListener('click', () => {
    box3.textContent = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  });
}
```

#### HTML (index.html) と CSS (css/style.css)

- index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="box1">Hello</div>
    <div id="box2">1</div>
    <div id="box3">Dice!</div>
  </div>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

- css/style.css

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
}

#box1 {
  background: pink;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 96px;
  user-select: none;
}

#box2 {
  background: pink;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 96px;
  user-select: none;
}

#box3 {
  background: pink;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 96px;
  user-select: none;
}
```

#### プログラムの仕様について

今回の質問はドットインストールが主催しているイベントの仕様にもとづき投稿しました。
[JavaScriptで『3つの箱』に動きを付けてみよう｜256times｜note](https://note.com/256times/n/nbab9f1f00998)

---

以上、ご確認よろしくお願い申し上げます。

Comment: まずは、エラーにならないスクリプトを、IF文に条件が設定されていないので、styleBackground 関数は動きません。

Comment: yyz さん。コメントありがとうございます。とりあえず質問の本文で記述したコードについて、エラーが出ないように修正しました。ですがエラーが出ないだけで、ボックスをクリックしたときに一瞬だけオレンジに変更するという仕様は満たされていません。もし修正の方法をご存知でしたらご教示を願います。